# UITableViewCell with AFNetworking setImageWithURL too big

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I have a "basic" table view cell and want to set an image:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:urlOfAvatar placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"none40"]];
```

Unfortunately, the result is that the image is too big for the cell. Is it possible make this look correct?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the image view's frame to the size you want, after setting image?

Comment: It will be asynchronous

Comment: There must be a way to get the image, and then in the completion block, set the image view and then size the image view as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a customized cell inherit UITableViewCell, and override layoutSubViews。

how to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866205/946434