# UIImage size in a tableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I have an image 1024x1024 and I want resize this image to fit into a tableView Cell. I have used this lines of code:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

   //New size is the size of the cell for me
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
   UIImage *imgFinal=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

   return imgFinal;

}
```

The problem is, when I visualize this image on the screen of Iphone6 or Iphone6+ the image appear blurred and a little bit pixelated. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set content mode as

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

For more info refer below link-

[iOS - UITableViewCell image adjust/resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861204/ios-uitableviewcell-image-adjust-resize?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: careful not to copy paste answers. Read others answers and check if its same.

Comment: @DHEERAJ, that's what I did, I didn't copy it as it it was, rather I mentioned the summary and directed the viewer to the original source.