# iOS >> UITableViewCell ImageView Property >> ContentMode doesn't have any effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, contentmode

In many cases using one of the 4 UITableViewCell 'of the shelf' styles is enough for what I need, except for one 'little' annoying thing: The cell.imageView.contentMode property is always set to Scale to Fill. If images have different ratios, it causes the cells labels to be pushed with different x per each Row. It looks ugly...

If I try to fix it in code, let's say in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, by addressing the property and assigning it to Aspect Fit, I get no warning or error, but it simply does nothing - i.e. it remains with Scale to Fill.

That means, that if I have an app where I'm not responsible for all the images presented in the table view and therefore cannot cut them in the same size - for example, if I wish to allow the user to select images from library or download etc... - I have to use a Custom Cell, even if all it has to have is an Image and a Label.

Does anyone know how to solve this using the default styles, without subclassing UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

In this [SO thread you have a couple of solutions for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788028/how-do-i-make-uitableviewcells-imageview-a-fixed-size-even-when-the-image-is-sm).

However, you will find that those solutions are just another way to create a custom cell. Or you need to create an ImageView at runtime or you just create a custom cell. As far as I know it is the right way to do it. I know that is annoying but the time you take to do a custom cell is way shorter than find hacky ways to go around that issue. Don't fight the framework :).

Comment: I'm 'not fighting the framework' for quite a while and therefor creating custom cells, even if there's no good reason to do so, just for this issue... but that seems elementary. I mean, it's possible to modify any of the other cell UI objects attributes, like the label text color, etc... the only thing that is not working is the image view content mode.........

Comment: I actually posted a request in Apple Developer Center... I guess I'm not the first one, but I said to my self "why not..."
Let's see what they say...
Maybe if everyone posted to them it may have some effect.......

Comment: I know that feeling and I have tried to find the answer myself. But the way I see this issue as a form to force an implementation. Apple gives you a template, but if you want a variation of that template or you want a new template just do your own class. Changing the visual form (or the template) in the cellForRow doesn't seem the proper way to do it.