# How to keep image size in tableview consistent

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a tableview which displays an image, issue is images are of different quality and size ratio so when they are displayed, they are shown like below[image]

my code on calling this is shown below

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:20.0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        Pupils *aPupil = [ArrayOfDisplayIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", aPupil.firstname,aPupil.secondname];
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@      Gender: %@ \n%@: %@   \n%@: %@", @"Class",aPupil.Class, aPupil.Gender, @"Date of Birth" ,aPupil.DOB, @"Date of Enrolment" ,aPupil.DateofEntry];
        cell.imageView.image = aPupil.picture;
    return cell;
 }
```

how can i keep these photos the same size no matter what.

so the picture is same size, same height, same width, or the text all starts in a straight line, just for neatness.

thanks

Comment: Can you define "same size"? At the moment both images are restricted to filling the height of the cell, what do you want to achieve? It may be helpful to add a mockup of what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITableviewCell and change the `layoutSubviews` method to set the cell's `imageView.frame` like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866205/1014164