# UITableViewCell ImageView Resize - Selected Row Changes Image Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, imageview, sdwebimage

I am setting an table cell ImageView from a URL like the following:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[account valueForKeyPath:@"Avatar"]];
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]];
```

I am then using a table cell subclass and resizing the image and making it round like the following:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,32,32);
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

This works great until I actually tap on a table row. It will then shift the image to the left some pixels.

It's only the images that aren't a perfect square. Example 100x75 instead of 100x100

I must be missing something small here? Here is a small image showing the offset:

[image]

FYI I'm referencing this post: [How do I make UITableViewCell's ImageView a fixed size even when the image is smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788028/how-do-i-make-uitableviewcells-imageview-a-fixed-size-even-when-the-image-is-sm)

**EDIT**

I've also tried this as the table cell `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

This seems to work, however, for some reason when the table view is loaded not all images are loaded in until I start scrolling

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:url options:0 progress: nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {

    // resize image code here, then set below
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}];
```

Comment: rather than setting bounds set frame inside layoutSubviews method as
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,32,32);

Comment: if I set the frame, the image is no longer centered

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did this

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = (self.imageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0);
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

I haven't change bounds at run time. Hope it helps

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. Also I need the images to be 32x32

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ended up just creating a custom UITableViewCell with a UIImageView defined width/height 32x32 and custom labels to essentially mimic the Right Detail view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `cell.setNeedsLayout()` after setting Cell's image view, if all images have same dimensions!

```
MenuController.shared.fetchImage(url: item.imageURL) { (image) in
        if let image = image {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
                cell.setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];

self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.frame.size.width/2-16,32,32);
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

}

Or you may try set autoresizingMask